# What difference does it makes to Ignore Route in RegisterRoutes vs Application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using Elmah. I need to access axd extension file through the browser.

Since it is a Web-Api project, I need to register IgnoreRoute(*.asx).

I have done this at RouteConfig.cs as well as WebApiConfig.cs

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I can understand that for API it will make no difference to set IgnoreRoute at RouteConfig level. However for WebapiConfig.cs I wrote this:

```
 config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("elmmah", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

It makes no difference whatsoever, and I cannot access elmah.axd

{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://x.com/api/elmah.axd'.","messageDetail":"No route data was found for this request."}

The moment I enter this at application , global asax it works!
So why these three areas are different?

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

An Insight question will be great!